# Is it possible to integrate google recaptcha in Lightning Web Component (without using static resource or vf page)?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to integrate google recaptcha into lwc . Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have to use a Visualforce page in a lightning component, because the recaptcha library is dynamic and can't be used within a Lightning Component. There is an interesting post from a Salesforce CTA that explains how to fix this: https://cloudmatters.blog/2017/11/19/google-recaptcha-versus-salesforce-lightning/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step explanation:

http://vagminecloud.com/blogs/Google_reCAPTCHA_Integration_in_Lightning_Web_Component.html